# Emulate IDispatchEx in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

C# 3.0 Extension methods add extensions to the base Type making calling that method on all *instances* of that Type legal.

Now, JavaScript I know implements IDispatchEx through which it's possible to add methods to a specific instance.

So how do I add a set of methods to an 'instance' of a C# class?  I know this is a Dynamic vs. Static Languages holy war territory. :)  Let me clarify my intention is NOT that.

I just want to be able to add a set of events to an interface depending on the class implementing that interface.

I was able to do that using Generics

```
inteface ISample<T> { T SupportedEvents; }  

class Sample : ISample<UIWidgetEvent>   {   }  
class Sample2 : ISample<NonVisualUIWidget> { }

class UIWidgetEvent { public EventHandler Clicked; }  
class NonVisualUIWidget {public EventHandler Expired;}

class TestSample
{  
    public void Test()
    {  
        new Sample().SupportedEvents.Clicked += ...
        new Sample2().SupportedEvents.Expired += ...
    }  
}
```

Then I didn't like `SupportedEvents` I want to be able to say

```
new Sample().Clicked +=...
```

Then I thought JavaScript (I know `C#` is not `JS` :))... AND `IDispatchEx`, `IL Weaving`, `Reflection.Emit` etc. etc. and thought may be there's a way to do this... [Design time support would be nice but I can live without]

Yes, I probably could do this "instance augmentation" with a Visitor pattern.
[Not sure if I could get the syntatic sugar though]

Comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could create a DynamicMethod instance for your "new" methods, but statically attaching them to an existing instance at runtime wouldn't work due to the fact it plain wouldn't compile.

You *might* (I haven't tried this) be able to emit the opcodes into an in-memory assembly, but that's about as far away from being "Syntactically sweet" as you can get (would involve a lot of reflection and InvokeMember calls, I would think)

It also might be worth looking into Extension Methods - although I've never tried attaching events or event-like methods via extension methods...and they are 3.5 only, so that may limit you.

The nicest looking, "pure C#" implementation is probably something very similar to what you've already got with the generic/interface setup...

Honestly, if you're looking for something with true "dynamic support" like this, I'd do this kind of stuff in a DLR-capable language (like IronPython) and call into it from your C# stuff.